# How to Remove axis Lines from chart in chart js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, chart.js

I drawn a chart using chart js like below

[image]

In this above chart i want to make a line thicker ( Pink Marked ) like other lines and also i want to remove x axis line ( Green Marked ). How can i do this please Help me.

Please see the fiddle Here [**Live Chart**](https://jsfiddle.net/9xrb0vhe/168/)

```
    var ganttchart = document.getElementById('bar-chart');
    new Chart(ganttchart, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                {

                    label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth : 15,
                    pointRadius : 0,
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 9
                        }, {
                            x: 3,
                            y: 9
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth : 15,
                    pointRadius : 0,
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: 3,
                            y: 7
                        }, {
                            x: 5,
                            y: 7
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {

                    label: 'Scatter Dataset',
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(246,156,85,1)",
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth : 15,
                    pointRadius : 0,
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: 5,
                            y: 5
                        }, {
                            x: 10,
                            y: 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(208,255,154,1)",
                    fill: false,
                    borderWidth : 15,
                    pointRadius : 0,
                    data: [
                        {
                            x: 10,
                            y: 3
                        }, {
                            x: 13,
                            y: 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                legend : {
                    display : false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        type: 'linear',
                        position: 'top',
                        gridLines: {
                            lineWidth:20
                        },
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtzero :true,
                            stepSize : 1
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes : [{

                        gridLines: {
                            display:false,
                        },
                        ticks : {
                            beginAtZero :true,
                            max : 10,
                            display:false
                        }

                    }]
                },
                animation: {
                  duration: 0
                },
                hover: {animationDuration: 0}
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find axes config options currently here: [Axes - Chart.js Documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/)

Axes config options has a global field `display` with the following description:

`If set to false the axis is hidden from view. Overrides gridLines.display, scaleLabel.display, and ticks.display.`

Here is how I have implemented it:

```
public chartOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            display: false,
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            display: false,
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change border to false.

```
const config = 
{
    type: 'line',
    data,
    options: {
        scales:{
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    border:{
                        display:false
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    border:{
                        display:false
                    }
                }   
            }
        }   
    }
}
```